# UltraGrid Win Hide all rows if no filter

Tags: vb.net, row, show-hide, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using UltraWin Grid 12 (Infragistics) for Win Forms (vb.net 2010 Framework 3.5) .

Is there a way to hide all rows and only show the filtered In rows?. I need to show nothing unless a filter is selected, and when all filters are unselected, hide all rows again.

I tried a For Each ... row.hidden = true, but no luck.

Comment: Is the filtering being done with the grids filtering or externally?

Comment: Internally using the Header Filter Row. My idea is to show nothing but filtered row, but on start Ultrawin grid fills up with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a draw filter to hide all of the rows when there aren't any that are filtered out:

```
public class HideRowsDrawFilter:IUIElementDrawFilter
{
    private UltraGrid grid;
    public HideRowsDrawFilter(UltraGrid grid)
    {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    public bool DrawElement(DrawPhase drawPhase, ref UIElementDrawParams drawParams)
    {
        if (this.grid.DisplayLayout.Rows.GetFilteredOutNonGroupByRows().Length == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public DrawPhase GetPhasesToFilter(ref UIElementDrawParams drawParams)
    {
        if (drawParams.Element is RowUIElement)
            return DrawPhase.BeforeDrawElement;
        return DrawPhase.None;
    }
}
```

To set the draw filter of the grid, use the following:

```
this.ultraGrid1.DrawFilter = new HideRowsDrawFilter(this.ultraGrid1);
```

Note that this only prevents drawing of the rows and they are still there so unless you disable them in another way, selection, editing, and activation will still happen.

Answer (score 0):

Cant u just set the default size to 0 ?

```
    myGrid.Rows.DefaultSize = 0
    myGrid.Refresh()
```

And when ever you are done getting the filters you need, just add the rows later.
And when unselected just put your defaultsize again.

Comment: Ultrawin grid does not have DefaultSize, I try Row.Height = 0 but no luck.

Comment: why are you filling, when you want to fill it later on a key press.